# Функция как константное выражение в вызываемой функции

Tags: c++, функции, c++11, constexpr

Есть такой пример:

```
constexpr int 
param(const size_t n) 
{ return n + 1; }
```

Аргумент этой функции известен во время выполнения программы, но сама функция может являться константным выражением. Но если ее вызвать в функции с аргументом вызывающей функции, то она не будет явлться константным выражением:

```
void 
foo(const size_t n)
{
    constexpr size_t k = param(n); //error
    //...
}
```

Почему функция `param`, являющимся константным выражением, не считается таковым в вызывающей функции?

P.S. подсказка как исправить ошибку не нужна...

Comment: И заголовок мне не по душе. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше его  было написать(или исправьте сами)

Comment: Нужно определить constexpr size_t k = param(n) как просто const

Comment: @Blacit, серьезно? Неужели я так плохо сформулировал вопрос, что не было понятно, что мне не нужен был ответ как исправить?....

Comment: Как понимаю, тебе нужно, чтобы всё выполнилось во время компиляции? Может, тогда и foo должен быть constexpr . Или у тебя какая-то ошибка вылезает?

Comment: @Blac, если в самом коде ошибка, то какая разница  как размещать функцию?...

Comment: Тогда действительно непонятно, что требуется. Я спросил, хочешь сделать, что вся программа выполнялась во время компиляции? Если да, то почитай [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну давайте подумаем. `constexpr` - это что-то, известное *во время компиляции*.

```
void 
foo(const size_t n)
{
    constexpr size_t k = param(n); //error
    //...
}
```

Как тут может быть `k` известно во время компиляции, если оно зависит от `n`, которое известно во время выполнения программы?

**Update**

Попробую своими словами :), не знаю, насколько они стыкуются с буквой стандарта - возможно, в каком-то пункте и не 100% точно.

`constexpr` для переменной означает, что она **обязана** быть определена во время компиляции.

`constexpr` для функции означает, что она **может** быть вычислена компилятором во время компиляции, т.е. что ее результат может быть присвоен 
`constexpr`-переменной (очевидно, что если ее аргументы - тоже `constexpr`).

Очевидно также, что если все вызовы такой функции выполнены во время компиляции - то ее просто незачем компилировать и превращать в код. Если не все - то она будет скомпилирована, как обычная функция, так сказать, с игнорированием описания `constexpr`.

Это дополнение внесло ясность?

Comment: от меня вопрос сразу) а можно как-то исправить, не меняя сигнатуры функции `param`? Я знаю что нельзя заставить `constexpr` работать _только_ во время компиляции, но можно ли убедить рассмотреть эти 2 функции как 1 или подобное?..

Comment: @Harry,  Нет, к сожалению, аргумент функции  param тоже известен в рантайм, но однако ее  результат  известен во время компиляции, аот что смущает

Comment: `нельзя заставить constexpr работать только во время компиляции` В смысле нельзя заставить? Это ведь его принцип, работать во время компиляции, если это позволяет программа. Лично я вопрос не понял про рассмотрение функций. @ARHovsepyan, Что, если сделать foo тоже constexpr?

Comment: @Blacit любую constexpr функцию можно вызвать в рантайме. https://ideone.com/SSgyBJ например. Поэтому и был вопрос.

Comment: @pavel Ну просто объявить `k` как `const`. Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @Harry, почитайте под основным вопросом комментарии. Я всё абсолютно тоже самое говорил.

Comment: @Harry да я  задал чутка неправильный вопрос. `constexpr size_t k = param(n);` никогда не может быть корректным же кодом? Или всё же может? Я это хотел спросить.

Comment: @pavel, безусловно, только вот какой смысл вызывать функцию в рантайме, которая обозначена как constexpr, если её функционал не используется? Нам и дали его, чтобы облегчить программе жизнь + самим сделать какие-либо вычисления, если необходимы.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то автора интересует не то, как исправить, а то - почему же у него ошибка. И как мне кажется, дело в том, что constexpr - функция будет вычислена на этапе компиляции только если во время компиляции известны ее параметры, в противном случае она вычислится в рантайме. А constexpr-переменная обязательно должна быть вычислена во время компиляции. Что в приведенном коде невозможно.

Comment: @pavel Может, если и `param`, и `n` - `constexpr`.

Comment: @Harry параметр функции нельзя сделать constexpr) но я понял почему и ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Ээээ.... а я что написал?... 8-/

Comment: @pavel Я имел в виду, например, `constexpr n = 5; constexpr size_t k = param(n);`

Comment: @Harry, то же самое, просто когда я писал комментарий, я еще не видел Вашего исправленного ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

У нас есть 2 функции.

Первая:

```
constexpr int param(const size_t n) 
{ 
return n + 1; 
}
```

Вторая:

```
void foo(const size_t n)
{
    constexpr size_t k = param(n); //error
    //...
}
```

Как я понял автора, он желает узнать почему функция `param` не вычисляется во время компиляции.
Для начала поймём, что такой `constexpr`.

> Спецификатор constexpr введен для того, чтобы заставить компилятор на
>   этапе кмпиляции создавать объекты и использовать их как константы
>   времени компиляции.

Смотрим теперь на наши функции, мы вызываем функцию param из функции foo. Зададим вопрос, а как выполнится эта строка `constexpr size_t k = param(n);`  во время компиляции? Никак, потому что мы не можем во время компиляции получить откуда-то параметр `n`, который требуется в функции `foo`.

Тут ***2 варианта выхода*** из ситуации:

1. Изменить код программы, чтобы все функции могли получить нужные параметры на момент компиляции.
2. Выполнить в рантайме и можно смело удалить `constexpr`.